# How can I store whether an element is selected or not so the page will remember it upon refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-cookie

I'm trying to adapt some code we use to store if a checkbox is checked or not in a cookie so that when the page refreshes it will remember which boxes were checked or unchecked. The problem is the new element I'm trying to store isn't a checkbox now, it's basically an icon that has a class('selected') toggled on or off placing a checkmark next to it.
This is the toggle function:

```js
//share - add class and check on click
$('.share-actions li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

And here's the cookie I'm trying to adapt:

```js
var $checkboxes;

// set the cookie
function setcookie() {
    var options= $checkboxes.map(function() {
        if (this.checked) return this.name;
    }).get().join(',');

    $.cookie('new_cookie', options);
}

$(function() {
    $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox').change(setcookie);
});

var alreadySetCookies = $.cookie('new_cookie').split(',');

for (var $cookie in alreadySetCookies) {
    $("input[name='" + alreadySetCookies[$cookie] + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
}
```

Comment: so what is the question? Code shown is for checkboxes....how do we know what needs to have class set to it ?Shouldn't use `for in` on array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting the presence of the `selected` class instead of the *checked* state. With minimal alterations to the original code.

The event handler:

```js
$('.share-actions li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    setcookie();
});
```

And the general cookie get/set code:

```js
var $checkboxes = $('.share-actions li a');

function setcookie() {
    var options = $checkboxes.map(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) return $(this).attr('id');
    }).get().join(',');

    $.cookie('new_cookie', options);
}

var alreadySetCookies = $.cookie('new_cookie').split(',');

alreadySetCookies.forEach(function(id) {
    $("#" + id).addClass('selected');
});
```

Each "checkbox" will need a unique ID for this to work:

```html
<ul class="share-actions">
    <li><a href="#" id="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="twitter">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="instagram">Instagram</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Updated `alreadySetCookies` loop to remove `for in`. If you need **oldie** support then drop [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) down to a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks, I had been trying to use .hasClass but couldn't seem to get the syntax right.